# Random replacement of files from the list ( batch-file)

Tags: batch-file

I need help creating a batch file.
The crux of the problem is that I need to randomly select a file (from the number of N files) and move it to another directory (replacing the old file)

I tried to use this code here:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("example.txt") do (
 call set $%%random%%=%%i
 )
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('set $') do (
 replace D:\test\Z\TEST /R
 exit /b
 )
```

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18946519/12343998)

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off

setlocal & set "_dir=%Temp%\Test\Target\."

for /f %%f in ('type example.txt^|find/v /c ""')do set /a "_max=%%~f-1"
set /a "_line=%random% * (-%_max% - %_max% + 1) / 32768 + %_max%"

if %_line% neq 0 set "_skip=skip^=%_line:-=%"

for /f %_skip%^usebackq^ ^tokens^=*^ ^delims^= %%i in (
    "example.txt")do move/y "%%~i" "%_dir%" & endlocal & exit /b
```

---

It is the case to get the path of your file to be copied, using a random draw in range 1 and total number of lines in your text file.

**1.** Use the range -/+total number of lines -1: `100 lines == range [-100-1] - [+100-1]`

**2.** Use this value to `skip=?` the previous lines, setting the `skip= resulting number`, and use it in `For /f` loop.

**3.** If `0` is the sorted one, the variable to `skip` is not set and does not interfere, making the first item to be obtained, no line is skipped.

**4.** Regardless of whether the lines are (`0` or other value up to a `maximum` of `-1`), use the line/file `%%~i` immediately exits the loop.

---

An option to remove the row a obtained in random...

```bat
@echo off

setlocal & set "_dir=%Temp%\Test\Target\."
for /f %%f in ('type ".\example.txt" ^| find/v /c ""
')do if %%~f geq 1 (set /a "_max=%%~f-1")else goto :eof

set /a "_line=%random% * (-%_max% - %_max% + 1) / 32768 + %_max%"
 
if %_line% neq 0 set "_skip=skip^=%_line:-=%"
for /f %_skip%^usebackq^ ^tokens^=*^ ^delims^= %%i in (
     "example.txt")do set "_file=%%~i" && goto %:^)
    
%:^)
findstr /v /c:"%_file%" <".\example.txt" >"%temp%\example.txt"
move /y "%_file%" "%_dir%" && move/y "%temp%\example.txt" ".\example.txt"
endlocal & goto :eof
```